# Compare 3 tables in SQLite

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite, uitableview

Originally, I have 2 tables. I normalized it since the relationship of this tables is many to many. Now I have 3.

#### Jobs

- jID PK
- jName
- jDesc
- jEarnings
- jTags

#### Course

- cID PK
- cName
- cDesc
- cSchool
- cProgram

#### JobsCourse

- ID PK
- jID FK
- cID FK

My app displays a tableview of the jobs

[image]

When clicked it displays the UIViewcontroller of jobs plus a tableview of the related course

[image]

How do I query the jobcourse table so that I can get all the related Courses to a certain job?

Comment: Suggestion: Use Core Data instead of an SQLite database.

Comment: I got confused with core data. Also, this is due on monday so it's hard to rewrite the code. So I might have to stick with sqlite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the two tables, e.g.:

```
SELECT course.* FROM course INNER JOIN jobscourse ON jobscourse.cID = course.cID WHERE jobscourse.jID = ?
```

That gets all entries from `course` where the `jID` in `jobscourse` is equal to some value.

Comment: the jID in jobscourse should be equal to the jID of jobs.. so that's `where jobscourse.jID = @"%d", jID` should I rename it? so that's not confusing?

Comment: @hazelvan Note, my use of `?` placeholder in my SQL is not by accident. You should not use `stringWithFormat` to insert values into your SQL statement. You should write SQL just like I did above, and then `sqlite3_prepare_v2` to prepare it and `sqlite3_bind_XXX` (e.g. `sqlite3_bind_int`) to bind values, and `sqlite3_step` to perform SQL. Not a big deal with numeric values, but for your string values it's _really_ important. Try inserting strings like `"Red Team" Project Lead` or `ABC's Project Manager` where you have quotation marks in the value with `stringWithFormat` approach: It will fail.

Comment: @hazelvan Should you rename jID? Sure, perhaps `jobID` would be less ambiguous. (And personally would also be consistent in plurality in table names, too, either consistently use singular in my table names (`job`, `course`, and `jobcourse`) or plural (`jobs`, `courses`, and `jobcourses`), probably leaning towards singular, myself.)

Comment: What I meant I was this:
`NSString *query= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT course * FROM course INNER JOIN jobsCourse ON jobsCourse.courseID = course.cID WHERE jobsCourse.jobID = %d",jID];`


how do I get the value of jID, when I click it? Coz this query may not be working since the jobs table is not included in the inner join. Should the code be:

`-(Jobs *)job:(int)jID {
Jobs *return = nil;
<insert query here>
<insert sqlite blahs here>}
return retrieve;}`

so that I can get the values via the jID? or am I wrong?

Comment: btw I'm not inserting values, i'm pulling them

Comment: Re selecting data vs inserting, that's fine, but the point about building SQL with `stringWithFormat` still stands. If this is just some class project, it's probably not a huge deal. But if it's for a production app, you really should be binding your text values, not building the SQL manually.

Comment: @hazelvan Regarding how to determine the `jID`, you're identifying the row with the `NSIndexPath` parameter to the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method. You presumably have some model backing your tableview which keeps track of the jobs in that original table view. You probably want to make sure that you're keeping the `jID` value recorded in that model. How precisely you do that is a function of the structure of your app's model, which you haven't shared with us, so there's no way we can answer that question.